# Display user.IsActive=true count(id) for all Profiles

Tags: soql

im trying to see how many active users are assigned to each profiles.

Im currently using

```
Select count(id)
From User
Where profile.name=' '
And user.IsActive=true
```

However, when doing this, i have to enter the profile names one by one and i have hundreds of them 
So im wondering if theres a query that will display all the Profiles and the count of active users assigned to them in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [the `GROUP BY` clause](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm).

Grouping by the profile name puts each different profile into its own bucket (of sorts), and the aggregate functions (like `COUNT()`) are applied to each bucket independently.

So you're looking for something like

```
[SELECT COUNT(Id), Profile.Name FROM User WHERE IsActive = true GROUP BY Profile.Name]
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! Thank you random stranger from the internet. This helps me so so so much!